# Simple server that cancels all the forked threads upon termination

Tags: multithreading, haskell, asynchronous, server

I'm writing a simple (chat) server inspired on [Simon Marlow's book](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/123000000092). I'm writing some unit tests where, at each case, I start the server, wait for it, and kill it.

What I would like is to define the main server thread in such a way that if it dies, all the threads spawned by it are terminated.

Currently the server looks as follows:

```
serve :: IO ()
serve = withSocketsDo $ do
  bracket acquireSocket releaseSocket doServe
  where
    acquireSocket = do
      putStrLn "Starting chat server"
      listenOn Config.port

    releaseSocket socket = do
      sClose socket
      putStrLn "Stopping chat server"

    doServe socket = forever $ do
        (h, host, port) <- accept socket
        a <- async $ talk h `finally` hClose h
        -- How do we cancel all the asynchronous processes if an exception is
        -- raised?
        return ()
```

If I run the tests using a simple `talk` function defined as:

```
talk :: Handle -> IO ()
talk h = do
  putStrLn $ (show h) ++ " bla bla bla ..."
  defaultDelay
  talk h
```

I can see, as expected, that the `talk` threads keep on "talking" after their parents have died.

In Marlow's book, it is shown how a hierarchy of threads can be created using `withAsync`, so that if the parent dies all of its children are terminated. Using this function, the `doServe` function could be rewritten as follows:

```
doServe socket = do
  (h, host, port) <- accept socket
  withAsync (talk h `finally` hClose h) (\_ -> doServe socket)
```

Note that I've replaced `forever` by a recursive call to `doServe`.

This solution has the expected behavior, and I like its simplicity, however, I'm worried about its the memory consumption.

I've sketched other solutions, but I cannot come up with something reasonably simple and more efficient. If I have to maintain a large data structures anyway, I'd rather stick to the `withAsync` solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of memory consumption are you observing?

Comment: If this is a performance question please post how you're compiling and running

Comment: No, so far I'm not experiencing any problems as I'm testing with with a limited amount of clients. My concern are the nested calls to `withAsync`.

Comment: Maybe a watchdog timer architecture?  Have the main loop sleep and write the current time to an MVar.  Have server threads check the current time against the MVar.  Instead of `forever` write and use `untilWatchdog :: MVar CTime -> IO a -> IO ()`.